# Не показывает Главное фото ( Featured Image ) Advanced Custom Fields Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Используется  Wordpress  и плагин  Advanced Custom Fields. Через этот плагин сделаны поля , в том числе и для загрузки Featured Image. Но этого поля не видно ( как показано на скрине) должно быть "Выберите файл" или что-то там еще.
Через браузер видно, что стоит класс для этого поля .hide-if-js . Раньше такого не было. Может как-то по ключу задать чтобы он всегда был виден?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если этот класс убрать (в браузере) , то появится поле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688

Comment: Проверьте не скрыто ли это поле в "Настройки экрана".

Comment: Да, действительно.... Спасибо большое :)